# MHA configuration problem with MariaDB10

Tags: mysql, mariadb, high-availability

I am using [MHA](https://code.google.com/p/mysql-master-ha/) (MySQL Master High Availability) over a MySQL/MariaDB master-slaves pool.

Here is my setup :

```
master1(10.0.0.1:3306) (current master) MySQL 5.1 (log-bin:enabled)
 +--slave1(10.0.0.2:3306) MySQL 5.1 (log-bin:disabled)
 +--slave2(10.0.0.3:3306) MySQL 5.1 (log-bin:enabled)
 +--slave3(10.0.0.4:3306) MariaDB 10 (log-bin:enabled)
 +--slave4(10.0.0.5:3306) MariaDB 10 (log-bin:enabled)
```

When slave2 (MySQL 5.1) is defined as candidate_master=1 in MHA config file, MHA works as expeccted (masterha_check_repl returns "MySQL Replication Health is OK.")

But when I disable slave2 as a candidate master (setting no_master=1 in MHA config file), setting slave3 as a candidate master does not work :

> None of slaves can be master. Check failover configuration file or
>   log-bin settings in my.cnf

(see complete log output below)

However log-bin are enabled on slave3. So what's going wrong with my setup? Is it an incompatibility with MariaDB 10?

Or maybe it is related to relay_log_purge warnings? But it works on MySQL 5.1, so I doubt it is related...

Here is masterha_check_repl output :

```
11:16| root@ha: ~ # masterha_check_repl --conf=/etc/masterha_bg.cnf
Wed Jul 23 11:16:57 2014 - [info] Reading default configuration from /etc/masterha_default.cnf..
Wed Jul 23 11:16:57 2014 - [info] Reading application default configuration from /etc/masterha_bg.cnf..
Wed Jul 23 11:16:57 2014 - [info] Reading server configuration from /etc/masterha_bg.cnf..
Wed Jul 23 11:16:57 2014 - [info] MHA::MasterMonitor version 0.56.
Wed Jul 23 11:16:57 2014 - [info] GTID failover mode = 0
Wed Jul 23 11:16:57 2014 - [info] Dead Servers:
Wed Jul 23 11:16:57 2014 - [info] Alive Servers:
Wed Jul 23 11:16:57 2014 - [info]   master1(10.0.0.1:3306)
Wed Jul 23 11:16:57 2014 - [info]   slave1(10.0.0.2:3306)
Wed Jul 23 11:16:57 2014 - [info]   slave2(10.0.0.3:3306)
Wed Jul 23 11:16:57 2014 - [info]   slave3(10.0.0.4:3306)
Wed Jul 23 11:16:57 2014 - [info]   slave4(10.0.0.5:3306)
Wed Jul 23 11:16:57 2014 - [info] Alive Slaves:
Wed Jul 23 11:16:57 2014 - [info]   slave1(10.0.0.2:3306)  Version=5.1.73-log (oldest major version between slaves) log-bin:disabled
Wed Jul 23 11:16:57 2014 - [info]     Replicating from 10.0.0.1(10.0.0.1:3306)
Wed Jul 23 11:16:57 2014 - [info]     Not candidate for the new Master (no_master is set)
Wed Jul 23 11:16:57 2014 - [info]   slave2(10.0.0.3:3306)  Version=5.1.70-log (oldest major version between slaves) log-bin:enabled
Wed Jul 23 11:16:57 2014 - [info]     Replicating from 10.0.0.1(10.0.0.1:3306)
Wed Jul 23 11:16:57 2014 - [info]     Not candidate for the new Master (no_master is set)
Wed Jul 23 11:16:57 2014 - [info]   slave3(10.0.0.4:3306)  Version=10.0.12-MariaDB-log log-bin:enabled
Wed Jul 23 11:16:57 2014 - [info]     Replicating from 10.0.0.1(10.0.0.1:3306)
Wed Jul 23 11:16:57 2014 - [info]     Primary candidate for the new Master (candidate_master is set)
Wed Jul 23 11:16:57 2014 - [info]   slave4(10.0.0.5:3306)  Version=10.0.12-MariaDB-log log-bin:enabled
Wed Jul 23 11:16:57 2014 - [info]     Replicating from 10.0.0.1(10.0.0.1:3306)
Wed Jul 23 11:16:57 2014 - [info]     Primary candidate for the new Master (candidate_master is set)
Wed Jul 23 11:16:57 2014 - [info] Current Alive Master: master1(10.0.0.1:3306)
Wed Jul 23 11:16:57 2014 - [info] Checking slave configurations..
Wed Jul 23 11:16:57 2014 - [warning]  relay_log_purge=0 is not set on slave slave1(10.0.0.2:3306).
Wed Jul 23 11:16:57 2014 - [warning]  log-bin is not set on slave slave1(10.0.0.2:3306). This host cannot be a master.
Wed Jul 23 11:16:57 2014 - [warning]  relay_log_purge=0 is not set on slave slave2(10.0.0.3:3306).
Wed Jul 23 11:16:57 2014 - [warning]  relay_log_purge=0 is not set on slave slave3(10.0.0.4:3306).
Wed Jul 23 11:16:57 2014 - [warning]  relay_log_purge=0 is not set on slave slave4(10.0.0.5:3306).
Wed Jul 23 11:16:57 2014 - [info] Checking replication filtering settings..
Wed Jul 23 11:16:57 2014 - [info]  binlog_do_db= , binlog_ignore_db= 
Wed Jul 23 11:16:57 2014 - [info]  Replication filtering check ok.
Wed Jul 23 11:16:57 2014 - [error][/usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2/MHA/MasterMonitor.pm, ln361] None of slaves can be master. Check failover configuration file or log-bin settings in my.cnf
Wed Jul 23 11:16:57 2014 - [error][/usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2/MHA/MasterMonitor.pm, ln424] Error happened on checking configurations.  at /usr/local/bin/masterha_check_repl line 48
Wed Jul 23 11:16:57 2014 - [error][/usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2/MHA/MasterMonitor.pm, ln523] Error happened on monitoring servers.
Wed Jul 23 11:16:57 2014 - [info] Got exit code 1 (Not master dead).

MySQL Replication Health is NOT OK!
```

Answer (score 1):

MariaDB had the wonderful idea of jumping from 5.5 to 10.x, making some applications to break. If you look at the source code for MHA, the place where you are getting your error, you can read:

```
# The following servers can not be master:
# - dead servers
# - Set no_master in conf files (i.e. DR servers)
# - log_bin is disabled
# - Major version is not the oldest
# - too much replication delay
```

As 5.5 < 10.x, MHA refuses to allow your MariaDB nodes as candidate masters. This is because in conventional MySQL versions, replication from `old_version -> new_version` is supported, but not always the reverse (new features can be added in more recent versions).

There are [some workarounds that may or may not help you](https://code.google.com/p/mysql-master-ha/issues/detail?id=70), but there is [no good official support](http://yoshinorimatsunobu.blogspot.com.es/2014/03/mha-056-is-now-available.html#Blog1_cmt-1824942786228537291) (and it makes sense, because it is not the developer's fault, and there are not (yet?) many MariaDB 10 users).

I would recommend you to avoid mixed environments. Replication on MariaDB 10 may be better or worse than MySQL 5.6, but it is [certainly incompatible](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2013/05/21/replication-in-mysql-5-6-gtids-benefits-and-limitations-part-1/#comment-1768866).

Comment: My goal was not to maintain a mixed environment with MySQL and MariaDB servers but use MHA to migrate from MySQL 5.1 to MariaDB 10 with minimal downtime. Unfortunately, as you say, in such a case the former master promoted as a slave would be in an older version than the new master.